# Using the REST api to create parent and child records in a single http request

Tags: rest-api, opportunity, standard-objects, opportunity-lineitem, order

I know that it is possible to insert Orders and Order Products together with a single HTTP request: [Salesforce Place Order REST api p23](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_placeorder_rest_api.pdf)

But when trying the same basic thing with Opportunities, I'm getting:

> < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   < ⋮
>   <[ {
>     "message" : "Opportunity: bad field names on insert/update call: OpportunityLineItems",
>     "errorCode" : "INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE",
>     "fields" : [ "OpportunityLineItems" ]
>   } ]

The response above was received from the following command (line breaks added for clarity):

```
curl -H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' -H 'Authorization: Bearer <sessionid>' 
https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Opportunity -v 
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' 
-d '{"Name":"Test",
     "StageName":"ClosedWon",
     "CloseDate":"2017-01-11T12:00:00Z",
     "OpportunityLineItems":{
         "records":
            [{"Name":"TestGenWattDiesel1000kW",
               "Quantity":1,"UnitPrice":1}]
     }
    }'
```

Is it possible to add an Opportunity and related Opportunity Line Items in a single HTTP request, or is that something that is unique to Orders and Order Products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you request payload is correct, the URI is wrong. According to Salesforce [SObject Tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm), you need to send request to

`/vXX.X/composite/tree/SObjectName` which in your case will be `https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/composite/tree/Opportunity`.

instead of `https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Opportunity`

Also make sure that each record has attributes specifying the `type` and a `referenceId`:

```
'{
  "records":[
    {"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","referenceId":"ref1"},
     "Name":"Test",
     "StageName":"ClosedWon",
     "CloseDate":"2017-01-11T12:00:00Z",
     "OpportunityLineItems":{
       "records":[
         {"attributes":{"type":"OpportunityLineItem","referenceId":"ref2"},
          "Quantity":1,
          "UnitPrice":1,
          "PricebookEntryId":"01u6F000009BK4K"}
       ]
     }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Update:

I read the document you shared and I believe that it is specific for order and order products.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I was reading an old printed-out copy of REST api developers' guide and didn't see it there. Thanks for your help!